# Pycharm add command

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose, pycharm

Pycharm Professional 2019.3

Ubuntu 18.04

I want to debug python script in container. I know that example below is overkill, but I want to make it simple as possible. How add entrypoint to Dockerfile?

**docker-compose.yml:**

```
version: '3'
services:
    python:
        build: .
        container_name: ppd
```

**Dockerfile:**

```
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
    python3-pip
ENTRYPOINT ["sleep", "5"]
```

**app.py:**

```
from time import sleep
for i in [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]:
    sleep(2)
    print(i)
```

I based on [pycharm configure](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/using-docker-compose-as-a-remote-interpreter.html)

[image]
[image]

If I run project without ENTRYPOINT everything works fine:

[image]

`docker ps -a --no-trunc --format {{.Names}}{{.Command}} | grep ppd`
`ppd "python3 -u /opt/project/build/app.py"`

It looks like pycharm gives CMD command, because when I add CMD to app.py it is ignored by docker.

When I add ENTRYPOINT in app.py, and start container I see:
[image]

`docker ps -a --no-trunc --format {{.Names}}{{.Command}} | grep ppd`
`ppd "sleep 5 python3 -u /opt/project/build/app.py"`

How combine ENTRYPOINT in Dockerfile with pycharm CMD?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you change `ENTRYPOINT` to `CMD` in your Dockerfile, everything will work fine.

`ENTRYPOINT` isn't a required command in a Dockerfile.  You generally need at least one of `ENTRYPOINT` or `CMD` but there's no specific requirement to use one or the other.  If you specify both, [the `CMD` gets passed as additional arguments to the `ENTRYPOINT`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#understand-how-cmd-and-entrypoint-interact).

In `docker run`, for example, it's very straightforward to override the `CMD` when you create a container:

```sh
docker run --rm myimage \
  python app.py
docker run --rm myimage \
  ls -lrt /app
```

This appears to be what PyCharm is doing too; it also matches the `command:` option in Docker Compose.

Since the command part just gets appended to the entrypoint part, specifying `ENTRYPOINT` as you've shown can cause some odd behavior, and you need some awkward workarounds.

```sh
 # ENTRYPOINT ["sleep", "5"]

 # sleep 5 python myapp.py
 docker run --rm myimage \
   python myapp.py

 # actually runs "python myapp.py" without the "sleep" wrapper
 docker run --rm \
   --entrypoint python \
   myimage \
   myapp.py \
```

This pattern means a couple of things:

- `CMD` should generally be a complete command line; you should expect it to potentially be replaced at container start time.
- If you provide an `ENTRYPOINT` you should make sure to run the `CMD` that gets passed as arguments.  If it's a shell script, ending it with `exec "$@"` will do this.
- Prefer `CMD` to `ENTRYPOINT` if you're not sure which to use (and aren't using both).
- If your program has a complex invocation, consider wrapping it in a shell script so that it can easily be launched with its standard set of arguments.

```sh
FROM python:3.8
WORKDIR /app
COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt
COPY . .
RUN chmod +x app.py

# No entrypoint; easy to specify an alternate command
CMD ["./app.py"]
```

```sh
# Entrypoint is a wrapper tool that takes a command as options
ENTRYPOINT ["wait-for-it.sh", "db:5432", "--"]
CMD ["./app.py"]
```

```sh
# Entrypoint is a shell script ending in `exec "$@"`
ENTRYPOINT ["./entrypoint.sh"]
CMD ["./app.py"]
```

(There is an alternate "container as command" pattern where `ENTRYPOINT` is a complete command and `CMD` is expected to be caller-provided options; the Docker documentation has [an example](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/#entrypoint).  That won't work with the PyCharm setup you're describing.)